# How do I use the ternary operator to add an optional part to an anonymous string in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl (sorry if the answer is obvious, but reading tutorials and documentation did not help). I have a statement in tcl that says:

```
startupitem.start "foo
\tbar"
```

What I would like to do is have the "foo" part become optional, depending on the outcome of 
`[variant_isset "alice"]` using the ternary operator and without using variables.

I've tried several things along the lines

```
startupitem.start "[variant_isset """alice"""?"""foo\n\t""":""""""] bar"
```

(of course with all kinds of escapes and combo's or the use of the double quotes inside the double quotes) but I haven't succeeded.

The outcome if the `variant_isset` expression returns true is that it is equivalent to

```
startupitem.start "bar"
```

Comment: When `variant_isset` evaluates to `true`, the string will contain `foo`. Pls. fix the wording or the example.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out Tcl's [`expr`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm) command, which introduces Tcl's expression sub-language incl. what you call the "ternary" operator `?`:

```
startupitem.start "[expr {[variant_isset "alice"] ? "foo\n\t" : ""}]bar"
```

If you happen to use a Tcl recent enough, you may want to prefer an outplace string assembly using [`string cat`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M5), rather than inplace:

```
string cat [expr {[variant_isset "alice"] ? "foo\n\t" : ""}] "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer to use the `if` command (which is very much the command version of the ternary operator), whose result is the result of the body script it evaluates. If there isn't an `else` clause, the result is the empty string if nothing else is chosen to do:

```
startupitem.start "[if {[variant_isset alice]} {string cat "foo\n\t"}] bar"
```

Or you can build a list and then `join` it:

```
set items {}
if {[variant_isset alice]} {
    lappend items "foo"
}
lappend items bar
startupitem.start [join $items "\n\t"]
```

This second approach tends to work particularly well when things get complicated.