# Returning Empty String from if statement in TCL

Tags: tcl

I'd like to grep for a value in a filename and return either a string or an empty string as a result.

I have this code

```
if {[catch {exec {*[list grep "MYTESTSTRING" $filename]} result] == 0} {
   [concat [file rootname $filename] .newext]
} else {
   ???
}
```

What goes in the ???

I've tried `puts ""` and `""` and `[concat [list "" ""]]` but none have worked as expected.

Comment: You want to search in the filename or the contents of the file?

Comment: You might want to check for [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029532/how-do-i-use-the-ternary-operator-to-add-an-optional-part-to-an-anonymous-string), explaining the available options (`if` vs. `expr`).

Comment: `return` might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

It appears the correct answer is to simply remove the `else`.

Comment: The result of `if` is the result of the script that is selected by the condition expressions (multiple because of `elseif`). If there is no script selected, the result is the empty string. Tcl's implementation strongly optimizes those empty strings, BTW.